# Unity: Vertical Group Layout Scroll doesn't work with Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch-event, vertical-scrolling

I'm doing a scrollable list of values.

I did it using an ***Item template*** setted up with ***[Layout Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwq9d.png)***, nested in a ***[Vertical Layout Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq261.png)*** object.

The ***Item Template*** is composed by an image and a text description.

The script that i use to populate the list is an easy ***for***:

```
for (int i = 0; i < details.Count && i < LenSize; i++){
    Transform transf = Instantiate(template, container);
    RectTransform trasnf2 = transf.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

    height = -3 * i;

    trasnf2.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, height);
    transf.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    transf.Find("Image").GetComponent<Text>().text = details[i].image;
    transf.Find("Desc").GetComponent<Text>().text = 
    details[i].description;
}
```

All works properly when I run the app from my PC, I'm able to scroll the list by "left click + drag up/down" or mouse scroll wheel.

My problem appears when i build the app and run it from my android device, i not able to scroll the list with the touchscreen.
(Touchscreen inputs work fine, I have some button and they work)

Can someone help me with my problem?

I found that I can use Input manager to catch input event... but I not sure how use it to "scroll" on Android, because if i change offset of object with ***Vertical Layout Group***, I move the entire object and I don't scroll the inside elements, else, if I change offset of child element (*Item Templates*) I change the single element position "breaking" the layout of the *Vertical Layout Group*;

I tried to find solutions, but I'm new and apparently nothing works when I apply it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you just trying to create a scrollable list of objects? If so, you do not need code to achieve this. I can post an example of a scrollable list using just UI components.

Comment: @TEEBQNE I tried scrollable list of object at the beginning, but i had problem with the UI. Now I don't remember exactly why (I did It some weeks ago), but I use Vertical Layout Group to due this. If you want, you can post and I'll try it if works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to make a scrollable list of UI objects here is a gif I made on that process. It runs through the layout and each component and it working.

[image: Example]

If you want to dynamically add objects to this list at runtime, use the `Panel_Content` transform and instantiate objects using `Instantiate(yourPrefab, Pane_Content.transform, false)`. Let me know if you run into issues with this example.

Comment: Hi @TEEBQNE, your solution is really similar to mine. I changed mine setup to use yours and ... Nothing change. Works when execute from unity/PC, But still not working when I use it on Android device, scroll doesn't work. :(

Comment: @GiorgiaRondin It is possible that there is another UI element blocking the clicks when your UI resales to mobile. Try building the project to windows/Mac and seeing if the issue is build only or android only.

Comment: You are right, I built the project to windows/Mac and the issue happen when i build the project. How can I find which UI element blocks the click?  Is there some trick or tips to find it?

Comment: @GiorgiaRondin I would make your Canvas mode scale to screen size. I would also disable the field Raycastable on all images or text that do not need to be clicked. There is a good way to debug it in editor but not a fantastic way in build. You can print the current hovered or clicked gameObject from the eventsystem and enable display debug logs when building the project. It's probably a fit to screen panel.

Comment: @GiorgiaRondin If you can post your full actual setup including your full scene hierarchy I might be able to help more.

Comment: I'm late, I'm really sorry. Anyway I tried on a new project. And after I don't know I many tries... I found out where the problem was. Now It work properly!!!!!! Thxxx you very very much ^^